# Java. My one class's input from user is not return to main program

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, instance-variables

Java. My one class's input from user is not return to main program

for user1.guess1's value here other class is returning only 0 instead of value entered by the user.
need help here how I can get the original value entered by the user.

```
class randtestdrive
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args){    
    user user1 = new user();
    user1.guess();

    int a = user1.guess1 ;
    int b = 5;

    //for user1.guess1's value here other class is returing only 0 instead of value entered by the user.
    // need help here how I can get the orignal value entered by the user.
    System.out.println(user1.guess1+" test A's value");

    if (a==b)
      System.out.println("Hit");
    else if(user1.guess1 != b)
      System.out.println("Missed!"); 
  }
}
class user
{ 
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
  int guess1;
  void guess()
  {
    System.out.println("Guess the random number in 1-10");
    int guess1 = in.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
int guess1 = in.nextInt();
```

is a local variable, not an instance variable, remove the `int`, and it will work.

This is your `user` class:

```
class user {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess1;

    void guess() {
        System.out.println("Guess the random number in 1-10");
        int guess1 = in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

When you create a new user, the instance variable is assigned `0` by default. And then you read into a local variable, which is discarded at the end of your `guess()` method. So you get a `0` in your main method.

Comment: It would make more sense for guess() to return an int (i.e., the value input by the user). Then there would be no need for the instance variable at all. You would just use `int a = user1.guess();`

Comment: @FredK absolutely, but he didn't ask for a code review :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Wow. I was not able to figure out what I missed and your suggestion worked. It would be great if you can explain me or guide me the topic it is relevant to in java. So that, I can sharpen my skills on that topic.